# Correct decode python string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to decode the string bellow:

```
st='arroz e feij\xc3o, bife ao molho de tomate, pts com quiabo\r\nSALADA: alface, r\xdacula, rabanete e cebola\r\nSOBREMESA: ma\xc7\xc3\r\nSUCO: Amarelo 3\r\n o card\xc1pio cont\xc9m gl\xdaten no p\xc3o. n\xc3o cont\xc9m ovos e lactose. traga sua caneca!'
```

Using:

```
st.decode(?)
```

But I don't now the correct codec.

Comment: I can't guess encodings on-the-fly, maybe someone else has this fascinating capability. Have you tried `'utf8'`?

Comment: If you're using Windows, try `'mbcs'` which takes the current OS code page.

Comment: What should the decoded string look like?

Comment: @ForceBru you can tell it's not utf8 because the hex bytes are singular. Utf8 will always have 2-4 hex bytes in a row.

Comment: No, I'm using Linux. This string I got of an internet page using urllib.

The correct decode is:
'arroz e feijão, bife ao molho de tomate, pts com quiabo\r\nSALADA: alface, r\xdacula, rabanete e cebola\r\nSOBREMESA: maçã\r\nSUCO: Amarelo 3\r\n o cardápio contêm glúten no pão. não contêm ovos e lactose. traga sua caneca!'.
I tried 'utf-8' and 'ascii'.

Comment: This is latin1. Check this out: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0223/.
`st.decode('latin1')` gives you decoded unicode string.

Comment: I tried this codec too. The only diference is that, when I print the string, star with the "u" indication, but didn't change the answer, still with the "\x**".
I could use search "\x**" and change one-by-one with char. But I think that is not the best way.

Comment: I found a solution after check the codecs used in [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet>).
The code that got correct this HTLM parsed text is

`tex = tex.decode('windows-1252').lower().encode('utf-8')`